# Cloudwatch docker agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, agent

i have a docker cloudwatch agent running on an Ec2 instance. My question is there anything specific that needs to be done for the cloudwatch agent to report the ec2 host metrics? Because nothing seems to be working as expected, but the container is up and running. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What is your purpose? If you want to monitor an ordinary EC2 instance then the CloudWatch agent should run without a container. [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance.html) explains how you should install an agent on your EC2 instance.

Comment: yes, i want to monitor the EC2 instance, and i thought i could have it running on a container.